# deleting ubuntu from the hard-disk when I have a triple boot

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

Currently I have a triple boot with `windows7,fedora 16,Ubuntu 11` . As I power my laptop I see the boot loader of ubuntu *(Grub)* that lists three OS's. I need to delete Ubuntu from my hard-disk ? How can I do this ? Someone told me that if you delete *Ubuntu* you won't be able to access windows or fedora. I don't understand this.

Anyways, I need to delete Ubuntu from my hard-disk and then reinstall it. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where your GRUB installation is: if it is in Ubuntu, deleting this distro will wreck your GRUB.

If you want to delete Ubuntu and keep Fedora I would suggest to install grub to the MBR from Fedora; the command should be

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

(or sdb, sdc, etc, depending on your system).

Comment: and how do I check if _grub_ has already been installed to the MBR ?

Comment: the fastest way seems to be [boot info](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/), as suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30341/how-to-know-the-partition-where-grub-is-installed).

Comment: I tried the script and [this is the output](http://suhail03.my3gb.com/bootscriptinfo.html). Can you please help me understanding the output

Comment: `Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda` this means your GRUB is installed inside the MBR and `looks for (,msdos6)/boot/grub on this drive`. As you can see from your configuration, **msdos6** is where `Ubuntu, with Linux 3.0.0-12-generic` resides (ergo, you Ubuntu installation)

Comment: I guess there are two `grubs`. One of the fedora and another of ubuntu

Comment: and `sda6` is the device that has grub installed for ubuntu ?

Comment: your MBR GRUB files are stored inside the sda6 partition (the Ubuntu one): if you plan to erase Ubuntu you have to `grub-install /dev/sda` from Fedora (to replace it)

Comment: okay. I understand `/dev/sda1,/dev/sda2...etc` but what does `/dev/sda/` mean ? When I will run `grub-install /dev/sda`,where will the grub be installed and what exactly am I doing ? _Please help me understand this_

Comment: executing `grub-install /dev/sda` will install grub to your sda's MBR

Comment: but why `/dev/sda` and not some other ? _(/dev/sda1..etc ?)_

Comment: because you have to install grub into the MBR if you want to boot windows

Comment: The `grub` for fedora is installed in `sda9` and _boot loader_ for windows is installed in `sda1` _(if I am right)_ . ? So this command basically installs grub of fedora into MBR ?

Comment: yes, that's exact

Comment: you know when I click the `windows` option on the boot screen of ubuntu,I don't directly boot into windows but again see the booting options namely `windows` and `fedora`. Earlier I used `EasyBCD` to dual boot windows and fedora before installing the third OS that was `Ubuntu`. So If I see the option of fedora on clicking the option of windows on the boot screen of ubuntu what does it tell !! ? Does it mean that bootloader of fedora is installed along side windows ?

Comment: I think you should create another answer for the last question

Comment: another answer ? I didn't understand you.

Comment: I meant question ;)